# Spring Boot, @Autowire into an unmanaged class using @Configurable and load time weaving

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a collection of unmanaged classes that I are instantiated outside of Spring. I've been attempting to use Spring AOP with load time weaving to `@Autowire` a bean into these classes but have so far not had any luck.

I've been testing using Tomcat 8 and Spring Boot 1.2.0.

My `@Configuration` where I attempt to set up class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class Config
```

Inside `Config` I define the bean I want to `@Auotwire` into my unmanaged classes:

```
@Bean
public StateProvider stateProvider() {
    //setup bean
    return new DynamoStateProviderImpl( );
}
```

The unmanaged bean looks like this:

```
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE, dependencyCheck = true,   preConstruction = true)
public class StateOutput implements UnifiedOutput {

@Autowired
private StateProvider stateProvider;
```

And I have the following deps inside my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

So far, I have not been able to see anything injected into `stateProvider` or been able to pull any info from the logs. I've also attempted setter style injection using

```
@Autowired
public void setStateProvider(StateProvider stateProvider){
    this.stateProvider = stateProvider;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to instrument LTW you'll need to either use the javaagent or place `spring-tomcat-weaver.jar` in the `\lib` folder and set up `TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader` in `context.xml`.

*javaagent example:*

```
-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6.SEC03/spring-agent-2.5.6.SEC03".jar
```

*ClassLoader example:*

```
<Context>
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classl oading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader" />
</Context>
```